# Keeping a DIV at the top of the page even when leaving

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to create an UI for my users to be able to browse foreign sites and save the elements inner text/html. Which I am having problem with achieving.

One of the problems is browsing the foreign sites through a DIV makes them look distorted due to the CSS being messed up.

Do you have any suggestions of how I can let my users browse foreign sites and let me implement my JQuery to their experience?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @Adam iframes don't work since I not allowed to manipulate them 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Foreign sites won't allow you to embed your JavaScript in them, for security purposes, no workarounds. The only thing I can think of is to write a small browser extension (which is allowed to embed JavaScript on any website), but it is more onerous for your users to ask them to install your extension.